# Filling a JComboBox with a loop

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Output Image:

[image]

I am working on a code to factorize an int number and adding it to a JComboBox through loop. I want to print it in this form in ComboBox:  "2x4". Code is given below. Arrangement is a JComboBox, `n` and `n1` are double.

Output is shown in abovepicture.

```
public void Factorization(double n)
     {
         for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
         {
            if(n%i==0) 
               {
              n1=n/i;
            String First,Second;
            First=Double.toString(n1);
            Second=Double.toString(i);
            String Factor[]= {First+"x"+Second}; 
            Arrangement.addItem(Factor);
                }
     }
```

Comment: and what does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Factor as a string array just use String only

```
public void Factorization(double n)
 {
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
        if(n%i==0) 
        {
             n1=n/i;
             String First,Second;
             First=Double.toString(n1);
             Second=Double.toString(i);
             String Factor = First + "x" + Second; 
             Arrangement.addItem(Factor);
        }
    }
}
```